# How to see which side of a rect a sprite is colliding with?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a platformer, and I need to have a collision detection function that tells me which side of the rect I just collided with. This way, I can have killing enemies, not fall, etc.

This is my code:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
import random

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        player_Left1 = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_Left.png').convert_alpha()
        player_Right1 = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_Right.png').convert_alpha()
        player_Left2 = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_Left2.png').convert_alpha()
        player_Right2 = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_Right2.png').convert_alpha()
        self.player_Right = [player_Right1,player_Right2]
        self.player_Left = [player_Left1,player_Left2]
        self.player_index=0
        self.player_Jump_Left = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_Left_Up.png').convert_alpha()
        self.player_Jump_Right = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_Right_Up.png').convert_alpha()
        self.player_Fall_Left = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_Left_Down.png').convert_alpha()
        self.player_Fall_Right = pygame.image.load('Player/Player_Right_Down.png').convert_alpha()
        self.Right = True
        self.Left = False
        self.moving = False
        self.falling = False
        self.image = self.player_Right[self.player_index]
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (50,336))
        self.gravity = 0
        self.ground = 336

    def player_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x +=2
            self.Right = True
            self.Left = False
            self.moving = True
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -=2
            self.Right = False
            self.Left = True
            self.moving = True
        if (keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]) and self.rect.top >= 336:
            self.gravity = -17
        elif not keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and not keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.moving = False

    def apply_gravity(self):
        self.gravity +=1
        self.rect.y += self.gravity
        if self.rect.top >= self.ground:
            self.rect.top = self.ground

    def animation_state(self):
        if self.rect.top < self.ground and self.Right and not self.falling:
            self.image = self.player_Jump_Right
            
        if self.rect.top < self.ground and self.Left:
            self.image=self.player_Jump_Left

        if self.rect.top <= self.ground-136:
            self.falling = True
        if self.falling:
            if self.Right:
                self.image = self.player_Fall_Right
            if self.Left:
                self.image = self.player_Fall_Left
        
        if self.rect.top >=self.ground and self.Right and self.moving:
            self.falling = False
            self.player_index += 0.1
            if self.player_index >= len(self.player_Right):self.player_index = 0
            self.image = self.player_Right[int(self.player_index)]
            
        if self.rect.top >=self.ground and self.Left and self.moving:
            self.falling = False
            self.player_index += 0.1
            if self.player_index >= len(self.player_Left):self.player_index = 0
            self.image = self.player_Left[int(self.player_index)]
            
        elif not self.moving and self.rect.top >=self.ground:
            if self.Right:
                self.image=self.player_Right[0]
            if self.Left:
                self.image=self.player_Left[0]
            self.falling = False

    def blockColl(self, sprite1, sprite2):
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite1,sprite2,False):
            gravity=0
    
    def update(self):
        self.player_input()
        self.apply_gravity()
        self.animation_state()
        self.blockColl(self,Block)


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Blocks/Block.png")
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (100,336))


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,550))
pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
player.add(Player())

blocks = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
blocks.add(Block())

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.fill((34, 153, 227))
    
    player.draw(screen)
    player.update()

    blocks.draw(screen)
    blocks.update()
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I tried using a normal `sprite.collide_any` to see if I could use it inside the class so my player would stand still. Unfortunately, that didn't work as my player would just pass through the block and no collision was detected.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this is to add a *desired* movement to your player, and then check it with a `.moveTowards()` function to your `Player()`.  Maybe something like:

```
def moveTowards( self, dx, dy, platforms_group ):
    """ Move the player up-to dx and dy pixels.  If something gets
        in the way, move as far as possible """
    self.rect.x += dx
    self.rect.y += dy

    # At the new position, would we hit anything
    collision_list =  pygame.sprite.spritecollide( self, platforms_group, False )
    if ( len( collision_list ) > 0 ):
        # Ok, so we *did* hit something, maybe multiple things.
        # Given the direction moved, work out how far we can go
        # NOTE: x and y are handled independently 
        if ( dx < 0 ):
             # sideways movement left caused collision
             right_sides = sorted( [ s.rect.right for s in collision_list ] )
             # biggest right-side is the closest
             self.rect.x = right_sides[-1] + 1  # maximum left-move possible
        elif ( dx > 0 ):
             # sideways movement right caused collision
             left_sides = sorted( [ s.rect.left for s in collision_list ] )
             # smallest left-side is the closest
             self.rect.x = left_sides[0] - 1  # maximum left-move possible

        if ( dy < 0 ):
             # vertical movement up caused collision
             bottom_sides = sorted( [ s.rect.bottom for s in collision_list ] )
             # biggest bottom-side is the closest
             self.rect.y = bottom_sides[-1] + 1  # maximum up-move possible
        elif ( dy > 0 ):
             # vertical movement down caused collision
             top_sides = sorted( [ s.rect.top for s in collision_list ] )
             # smallest top-side is the closest
             self.rect.y = top_sides[0] - 1  # maximum down-move possible

# Obstructed movement is now corrected.
# Player has been moved.

return collision_list  # this was expensive to make, so maybe it's useful
```

So the algorithm here is:

- Move the desired direction
- Make a list of anything we collided with
- If we did hit something

  - find the closest thing we hit by sorting edge-positions
  - Adjust movement to 1-pixel *before* that object

The key thing is knowing which direction the desired movement is (e.g.: positive `dx` or negative `dx`), and then using that to fetch the left or right "collision sides" from the list.  Obviously up & down is the same, except a different direction.

We're using a `dx` and `dy` ("d" meaning "delta" or "change") to hold the current movement of the player.  So you don't need to store `player.left`, etc.  If `dx < 0`, it's moving left, if `dx > 0` going right.  Obviously if `dx` is zero, the player is not moving left or night.

The `spritecollide()` makes fetching the list of objects we hit really simple.  Just remember to keep the position and dimensions of your sprites correct in `sprite.rect`.